# Transform string to Date

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Please I try to convert string to Date in anyoint studio but I get this error in Avanced rest client "Cannot coerce String (22/03/2012) to Date, caused by: Text '22/03/2012' could not be parsed at index 2.

please can I some one help me .
Thanks advanced .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It’s an interesting problem you’ve got there. Could you provide a [mre] so that someone can figure out what goes, please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't use the right format for the conversion. You need to set the Date format if it is not the default.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var inputString="22/03/2012"
---
inputString as Date { format:"dd/MM/yyyy" }
```